# time is not saved in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, time

I have postgresql db. Time is set in wrong way. When I try to set it to my timezone like this:

```
set timezone="Europe/Warsaw";
```

it is set. But everytime I am logged off and back, time is reset to "local" timezone and time is set to previous value((( How can I save it? 
I have tables with columns which shows the time when rows where updated. And this time is wrong(((

Comment: What do you mean by "time is lost"? You mean timezone of your client connection or timezone for your data? In case of the latter that is how TIMESTAMP data type works - it is timezone independent and translating stored value to actual date and time depends on the timezone of the client.

Comment: I have columns in my db with triggers. These triggers update the time when the row was modified. The time is set incorrectly. My tryings to change it using set timezone does help only for my current session((((

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer:

```
ALTER DATABASE postgres SET timezone TO 'Europe/Warsaw';
```

It works fine for me)))